# Image loaded in Chrome Dev tools but not into site

Tags: html, css, image, loading

CSS have been playing up and it has become a struggle for me to add just an image to my basic website. I am loading it in the correct path and it is in the correct path. The way I structured it is to place a blank div and give it an ID with this ID I edit it on CSS and load the image as a background image, however, ofcourse it does not load. When I run the server and use chrome's dev tools I find that the CSS has found the image (even displays a thumbnail of the image!) but still does not load anything into the site.

Relevant HTML:

```
{% load staticfiles %}    
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'QMS/styles.css' %}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'QMS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' %}">
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'QMS/jscript.js' %}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id = inputImg></div>
    <div id = outputImg></div>
    <div id = leadershipImg></div>
    <div id = supportImg></div> 
    <div id = circle></div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#inputImg{
    background-image: url('../QMS/images/inputs.jpg') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#outputImg{
    background-image: url('../QMS/images/outputs.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#leadershipImg{
    background-image: url('../QMS/images/leadership.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: 80px;
}

#supportImg{
    background-image: url('../QMS/images/support.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    bottom: 40px;
 }
```

[image: This is an image of the Dev tools view]
This is a screenshot from inside the dev tools. (Ignore the error it was from me typing something into the command line without realising)
[image: Directories]
These are my pathways for the CSS and images, within the seperate CSS folder I used to contain the CSS file but I changed it to and from for testing and in its current location seems to work the best. (Putting it into the CSS folder had no effect on the error)
[image: Image of site]
So this is the final image, this is what my website looks like and as you can see it is missing the images/boxes that the CSS should have loaded in.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!! Cheers.

Comment: You haven't given `outputImg` a width or height so both are zero pixels.

Comment: @Turnip I thought this was about to be an embarrassing fix haha. I just added width&height to all the relevant CSS classes and nothing has changed

Comment: Have you tried to change the `z-index` to a positive value?

Comment: @Johannes yeah I had before hand and I just tried then. Unfortunately no help.

Comment: Also `<div id = inputImg>` should be `<div id="inputImg">` etc (no space around the `=`, and the id name in quotes)

Comment: Works fine https://jsfiddle.net/gwcux9gs/ if you add width and height

Comment: Hmm, still not working for me I tried to change the dimensions I provided before but no result. Any suggestions on why it might work on jsfiddle but not on my local server?

Comment: @Turnip Sorted it, thanks for the help.

Comment: What did you do to 'sort it'?

Comment: @BattlFrog Unfortunately I cant remember, I tried looking for this code but I'm was very beginner when I started it so I think I deleted it. If you're facing a similar problem have you followed those steps given to me? If not have you tried to use IMG tag in the HTML? (I find that works a lot more consistently)

Comment: Yes I changed to img tag and it is working fine.  Wish I could figure it out though.  I am building a bunch of similar web appsthat sit on a companies internal web server and the image is the comapny logo that I added to each site in the same way, as background-imgage in css and they all worked until this latest one.  Oh well.

Comment: @BattlFrog Yeah its weird I find CSS somewhat temperamental. I'm glad its sorted though.